# APEX 19 Wizard Master-Details Issue

Tags: oracle-apex

The wizard for a master details completes *however* the updating for the detail is not working as required.

*Creation process-> Create Page -> Master Detail then Drill Down*

I have created this same issue a couple of time.  Am not experienced enough to determine what the issue is.  Has anyone come across this before?

Here is the page with the master detail relationship...

Master
[image]

Detail
[image]

Master-Detail screen
[image]

Master-Detail error when a detail is changed and **Apply Changes** is clicked
[image]

I have double checked the master (orders) and detail (order details) and the correct original values are being displayed.  So my belief is that the navigation between them is correct.
I can create a header by itself.  I can delete both master and detail details.

- When I attempt to edit the detail the value displayed changes from the original value to the value at the bottom of the grids column???
- If I type in a new value then I get the Master-Detail error screen?

I made **no** changes from the original master detail relationship created.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp thanks still learning the formatting options here.    Do you have any feedback on the issue, it looks like a software bug but I'm resistant to say that as I still just trying to learn.  Plenty of Oracle Forms and Reports knowledge but basically 1/2 a book of step by step APEX so far.

Comment: I converted the tags to images because new stackoverflow users aren't able to embed images.

Comment: WIth regards to your question, unfortunately there's not enough details to be able to guess what is causing your issues. Firstly, you have described two issues which may or may not be related. Secondly, you haven't shown all the attributes that might affect this outcome. I would look at the PK column attributes to make sure they're configured correctly. I would check the DML process and how it is set up for detecting overwritten updates.

Comment: It's difficult to give a specific plan of attack though without direct access to a minimal sample app that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Ok I learnt something here. The primary key was not the Order Id (although used in both Order and Order Items table), within the Order Items table itself, it was in fact other items. This was causing the issue. So I change the choice, within the wizard, to use the Row Id. Still used the Order Id for the Master Detail Foreign Key relationship. Have done a change and it appears to work ok. Your suggestion about PK column attributes was the key so Thank You!

Comment: That sounds right. I would expect the PK on the detail table to be different to that of the master table - usually (exception is if they have a 1:1 relationship).